# Should i restrict the scope of my work according to the conference theme?

Tags: publications, conference, computer-science, paper-submission

I'm writing a paper for a **good conference** in computer science with specific themes in Data mining. I checked their scope of topics and their programs for the last 3 cycles of the conference, and i noticed they always have a session related to "**Topic-X**" (time-series) which is also mentioned in their CP's themes.

Well, i used my work (classification algorithm) to solve the problem regarding "**Topic-X**", but i also found that it is applicable to a much broader range of problems rather than only "**Topic-X**". But the conference does not have a session for a broad topic like that, although it is included in their CP's themes.

So i'm thinking:

1- If i write and name the paper related to "**Topic-X**" there is a high chance to get accepted there as they have a session for that. However, then i'd deliberately restrict the application scope of my method.

2- If I use it in the general case while also including "**Topic-X**" in the experiments, it may not directly fit the conference's **session-X** and may lose its chance to get accepted there.

3- If go with **plan 1** but also include other types of problems in the experiments, I'm afraid it may sound awkward or out of the scope of the paper.

Should i ask the conference chair or is it more awkward?!

Comment: "it may not directly fit the session-X and may lose its chance to get accepted there." This seems to be an error in your thought process: Papers are usually assigned to sessions *once they are accepted*. A lack of suitability of your paper for a distinct session should not be a reason for the rejection of your paper.

Comment: @lighthousekeeper: they have "Machine learning" and "data analysis" mentioned in their themes, but i noticed they never had a session dedicated to topics like that without being related to specific applications (ex. speech or text or streams etc.)